# how to complete fit_transform on tuple, or be able to complete a fit_transform on the data, by changing tuple to...?

Tags: python, tfidfvectorizer

So first question: I read up on this error and it says it is type: tuple, so I am confused what the error is and what to do to fix it. A beginner, so please provide detailed suggestions. tried changing (df_x) to [df_x], as per instructions in similar question, without success.

```
cv2=TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True,min_df=1),#stop_words='english')
        updated_x2=cv2.fit_transform[df_x]
        fn2=cv2.get_feature_names()
```

```
        AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
        <ipython-input-52-ddf0f04628ff> in <module>
        1 cv2=TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True,min_df=1),#stop_words='english')
---->   2 updated_x2=cv2.fit_transform[df_x]
        3 fn2=cv2.get_feature_names()

        AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'fit_transform'
```

Comment: You have a comma at the end of the `cv2=...` line, this is creating a tuple. Remove the comma

Comment: @Gems Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem, that way the question will be marked accordingly for future users

Answer (score 1):

```
cv2=TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True,min_df=1),
```

creates `cv2` as a `tuple` because of the unintended trailing comma. If you adjust your comment to precede it, i.e.

```
cv2=TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True,min_df=1)#, stop_words='english')
```

It should get rid of that error